# How to write elegant code using File.mkdirs() in java?

Tags: java, file, io, mkdirs

I need a directory to save files but I am not sure whether it exists.
So I need to check if it exists first, and create it if necessary.

```
File saveDir = new File("/tmp/appname/savedir/");
if(!saveDir.exists()){
    saveDir.mkdirs(); 
}
```

As above, there is a question.
Method "saveDir.exists()" returns a boolean value which indicates if the file path exists.

Of course, I could write some redundant and ugly code to work.

Is there a way to write some elegant code to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 8):

is your question about "redundant" check-directory-exist code, or you need to create a directory and all missing parent directory?

I believe both can be easily done by using FileUtils in Apache Commons IO:

```
FileUtils.forceMkDir(new File("/some/missing/parent/directory/foo"));
```

Answer (score 6):

There is always

```
if(!file.exists() && !file.mkDirs()) { // handle the failed to create situation... }
```

Comment: Or: `if(!(file.exists() || file.mkDirs()))`

Comment: Or `if (!file.mkdirs())` @WBT.

Comment: @EJP OP doesn't want to execute the code in the body of the `if` if the directory already existed.

Answer (score 3):

Elegance is more a subjective thing, but if you want to check whether the directories are actually created, check also the return value of [`File.mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29). If it returns `false` it depends on your application on how to handle it (e.g. throw an exception).

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in pre-testing. It just introduces a timing window during which the actual status can still change, so you can still be wrong. Just call `mkdirs()` and test the result it returns. If false, it did nothing; if true, it did something. *What* exactly it did is really of no actual interest.

Comment: If mkdirs is called when the path already exists, it returns false instead of true. File#mkdirs differs in its behavior from unix `mkdir -p`. So your statement about it having done something is accurate, but does not address the OP's problem of trying to ensure a path exists before using it.

Comment: @ChrisBetti That's what I said. If you call it, you've ensure that the path exists.

Comment: Where you state "Just call mkdirs() and test the result it returns," that part is incorrect. mkdirs() returns false in the following cases: 1) if it could not create the directories. 2) if the directory existed prior to the call.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a static method in a utility class which saves a file *and* automatically  creates all necessary directories at the same time. The code *inside* the utility method may be a bit verbose, but this way, you can keep that ugly, verbose code *out* of your high-level application logic. And in future projects, you can always reuse the utility. After you split this code off into a utility method, it will also be easy to test in isolation.

I recommend you try to think in terms of building utilities and then using the utilities to build the actual application, rather than mixing detailed, low-level code in everywhere. The utilities you write may be useful on later projects, but that's not the primary goal: even if you only use a utility method on one project, and *even if* it is only called from *one* place in the higher-level code, it is *still* worth it if it helps make the higher-level code clearer. I don't remember which book helped me to get this concept; it may have been *The Practice of Programming* by Kernighan and Pike, or *The Art of UNIX Programming* by Raymond, or *On Lisp* by Graham -- or probably all three. (Of course, it's also important to know your language's standard library, so you don't start writing utilities which are already written for you.)

Comment: I very much agree with your opinion about code design, thanks for your advice.

Comment: The utility method already exists. It is called `File.mkdirs()`. No other code required.

Answer (score 1):

As @stephan mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11823798/492561)

> Elegance is more of a subjective thing

But since you asked for it

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileBuilder {
    File file;

    public FileBuilder(String path) {
        file = new File(path);
    }

    public FileBuilder createIfDirDoesNotExists() {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        return this;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
class test {
    public test() {
        File file = new FileBuilder("/tmp/appname/savedir/").createIfDirDoesNotExists().getFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 File dir = new File(dirPath);
 if(!dir.exists())
     if(!dir.mkdirs()) {//throw or handle exception here.}
```

You would still need to throw or Handle SecurityException that might be thrown during File.mkdirs()

Answer (score -1):

file.exists() will return whether a directory OR a file exists. You can also use isDirectory() to check if the file path is a directory or not

```
if (file.isDirectory()){
      //do somethign because this directory already exists
}
else if (file.isFile()){
      //do somethign because this file already exists
}
else {
     boolean created = file.mkdirs();
     if (!created) {
        throw new IOException("Cannot create directory " + file);
     }
}
```

As to how elegant this is.... I would wrap it in a util method personally to hide some of this extra cruft java makes you write

Comment: Everything except the `mkdirs()` is a complete waste of time here.